# Understanding the pullback of the differential of the projection map of a cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, co-tangent-space

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold. Then any point $p \in T^*X$ is of the form $p = (x, \xi)$ where $x \in X$ and $\xi \in T^*_xX$. We have the projection map
$$\pi: T^*X \rightarrow X \\ (x, \xi) \mapsto x$$
and the pushforward
$$d\pi_p: T_p\big(T^*X\big) \rightarrow T_xX.$$

Recalling that a one-form on a manifold $M$ is a function defined on $T_pM$ for $p \in M$, I would expect that
$$(d\pi_p)^*: T^*\big(T_xX) \rightarrow T^*\Big(T_p\big(T^*X\big)\Big) \tag{1}$$
because a one-form on $T_p\big(T^*X)$ takes as an input a vector in the tangent space to $T_p\big(T^*X\big)$.

However, the definition of the tautological 1-form is instead given by
$$(d\pi_p)^*: T_x^*X \rightarrow T_p^*\big(T^*X\big). \tag{2}$$

Can anyone help explain why the definition in (2) makes sense as opposed to (1)?

Comment: We are just taking the dual of the linear map $d\pi_p$.

Comment: If $L:V\to W$ is a linear map, then the pullback $L^*:W^*\to V^*$ is the induced map on the dual spaces. You already noted that $d\pi_p:T_p(T^*X)\to T_x X$. Dualise this and you get $d\pi_p^*:T_x^*X\to T^*_p(T^*X)$.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Sorry I am still having some trouble. The dual of $d\pi_p$ would be a map from the dual of $T_xX$ to the dual of $T_p\big(T^*X\big)$. Viewing $T_xX$ as its own manifold means it has its own tangent space, $T(T_xX)$. So wouldn't its dual be $T^*(T_xX)$, and similarly for $T_p(T^*X)$?

Comment: @QuaereVerum I think part of my confusion is that equation (2) in my original post seems to be the same thing as just $\pi^*$, so I am confused what is the difference between $\pi^*$ and $(d\pi)^*$.

Comment: No, you are already in a vector space with linear maps.  There is no need to introduce another bundle where the resulting map is just constant on all fibers.

Comment: You could (should?) think of vector bundles and operations between them as doing "parameterised linear algebra". If the concepts makes sense at the level of vector spaces, they should make sense at the level of vector bundles.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry I'm still not getting it. The map $(d\pi_p)^*$ sends a one form on $T_xX$ to a one form on $T_p\big(T^*X\big)$. But a one form on $T_xX$ is an element of the cotangent space to $T_xX$, i.e. $T^*\big(T_xX\big)$ right?

Comment: @user10354138 I found my mistake, I was using two sources that use conflicting notation. One denotes the pull back of $f$ as $f^*$, and the other denotes it as $(df)^*$. I incorrectly thought the latter meant to first take the pushforward and then pull them back, but this seems to be incorrect.